# Dataframe count of values in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have the following data frame:

```
0 a,c,d
1 a
2 e,z
3 a
```

and I want to keep only the rows that have more than 1 item on them.
An expected result would be:

```
0 a,c,d
2 e,z
```

I have tried using value_counts but it's not working as I thought. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

** Edit **

As requested  in the comments, the code i use to make the dataframe:

```
g = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].groupby(['A','B'])
g = g['C'].unique()
dataf = pd.DataFrame(g).reset_index()
dataf['C']
```

** Edit2 / Solution **

Thanks to [Pierre Lafortune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4564247/pierre-lafortune) i now have the following solution.

```
x1 = dataf['C'].apply(lambda x: len(x) != 1)
dataf['C'][x1]
```

Comment: Could you post the code that makes the dataframe?

Comment: I updated the post adding the code you requested

Comment: Maybe `df1[map(lambda x: len(x) != 1, df1)]` but I think it returns a Series. Not sure if someone else can help improve.

Comment: Based on your answer i used the following `dataf['C'].apply(lambda x: len(x) != 1)` but i get True and False as results. I want to get the rows with their values.

Comment: You can save that output to a variable like `x1 = dataf['C'].apply(lam.....` Then you can subset the DataFrame/Series with it. `dataf['C'][x1]`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Can you write it as an answer to mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible way:

```
df1[map(lambda x: len(x) != 1, df1)]

0    a,c,d
2      e,z
```

The logical index can also be used to subset with `.apply`:

```
df['x'].apply(lambda x: len(x) != 1)

0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: x, dtype: bool
```

With this index:

```
df['x'][x1]

0    a,c,d
2      e,z
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['a','b','c','d'], ['c','d'], ['e']])
>>> df
   0     1     2     3
0  a     b     c     d
1  c     d  None  None
2  e  None  None  None
```

Perhaps, not so elegant but should work.

Generate a mask

```
mask = [np.count_nonzero(x) > 1 for x in df.iloc[:, :]]
```

Filter values

```
df[mask]
```

**EDIT**

An elegant version

```
df = df[df.apply(lambda x: np.count_nonzero(x) > 1, axis=1)]
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Can you post the data frame you used and the output you get?

Comment: I get the following error `ValueError: Item wrong length 3 instead of 4.`. I think that happens because i have strings.

Comment: @PierreLafortune Added the dataframe I used.

Comment: @Fotis The idea is to generate a `mask` array i.e., collection of True, False values corresponding to rows you wish to select. Then use that to make your selection.

Comment: The data you set up does not reflect the data given in the example.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I wish i could up vote it but i don't have enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `df.count()` would be more intuitive.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a','b','c','d'], ['c','d'], ['e']])
df = df[df.count() > 1]

#Result
   0  1     2     3
0  a  b     c     d
1  c  d  None  None
```